# BigQuery - Multiplying a column with descending coefficient for a rolling year starting from a specific date

Tags: google-bigquery

I have 2 columns in my table; Timestamp (starting from 2020-01-01 00:00:00, ending in 2050-12-31 23:00:00 for 1 Hour interval) and Production data for each hour. I want to degrade this production data by 0.5% year-over-year. The first year's production data will not be changed. In the second year, it will start to degrade (multiplied by the same value for the whole year).

If I want to apply degradation on the production column starting from 2021-08-01 00:00:00, how can I do that? For instance, the first year's date will include between 2021-08-01 00:00:00 and 2022-07-31 23:00:00 and production will be multiplied by 1. In the second year (2022-08-01 00:00:00 - 2023-07-31 23:00:00) production will be multiplied by 0.995..

Comment: Sample Input/Output will greatly help us answer your question.  An additional question, do you need future hourly records for each production timestamp record, or just yearly records (to the hour) with the factor applied?

Answer (score 1):

First year of degradation has coefficient 0.995, second year 0.995*0.995 etc. 
You can split problem to two parts:

1. specifying groups of rows with same level of degradation (`g` column below) and
2. multiply production data by precomputed coefficient.

Query:

```
#standardSql
with sample as (
select  timestamp '2020-01-01 00:00:00' as t, 100 as d union all
select  timestamp '2020-08-01 00:00:00', 100 union all
select  timestamp '2021-01-01 00:00:00', 100 union all
select  timestamp '2021-07-31 23:00:00', 100 union all
select  timestamp '2021-08-01 00:00:00', 100 union all
select  timestamp '2022-01-01 00:00:00', 100 union all
select  timestamp '2022-08-01 00:00:00', 100 
), partial_result as (
  select t,d, div(greatest(date_diff(cast(t as date), cast('2020-08-01' as date), month),0),12) as g from sample
)
select t,d, d*pow(0.995,g) as newd
from partial_result
```

`newd` can be used in update statement.

Note in case you wanted to round values on n-th level and compute n+1-th level values from rounded values on previous level this approach is not usable.